# Why am I getting Divide By Zero Exception on Azure Web Sites?

Tags: azure-web-roles, epplus, azure-web-app-service

I've had EPPlus (Office Open XML) working on a Azure Web Role for some time now, but I've been experimenting with Azure Web Sites lately and there I'm getting a very weird error;

```
[DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.]
   System.Decimal.FCallDivide(Decimal& d1, Decimal& d2) +0
   OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawing.SetPixelWidth(Int32 pixels, Single dpi) +465
   Compliance.Net.CommonCode.PivotGenerator.GeneratePivotTable(ExcelWorksheet dataWorksheet, ExcelWorksheet pivotWorksheet, Int32 endRow)
```

I am getting this on the same data and code as is running on Azure Web Role.

*Edit:*
The offending lines look like this:

```
 var chart = pivotWorksheet.Drawings.AddChart("PivotChart", eChartType.ColumnClustered, pivotTable);
 chart.SetPosition(endRow + 2, 20, 1, 10);
 chart.SetSize(600, 400);
```

Please note that I have made sure that 'endRow' is > 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure how this could be specific to Windows Azure Web Sites, by the looks of the code samples you've provided there isn't anything accessing information of the underlying environment.

Comment: Wouldn't think so... But when I removed the 'SetPosition' and 'SetSize' calls it works! So that's how I 'fixed' it.

Comment: Yeah that would work because that's the offending code. I'd like to understand what could be causing the issue. Could you tell me what where to download EPPlus so that I can see what `SetPosition` is doing?

Comment: I've been getting the same thing when adding an image to a spreadsheet. Identical code identical data works perfectly in other environments, but div/0 in an Azure website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having had the same issue myself I've pulled the EPPlus source and done some sleuthing.

The issue is in ExcelWorkbook.cs line 283 which calls

System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(string,Font).Width

which appears to return Zero in an Azure website.

I've just added a line

if (_standardFontWidth == 0) _standardFontWidth = 7;

(7 was the value I was getting locally so it will do as my default - your mileage may vary) meaning I ended up with

```
    public decimal MaxFontWidth 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_standardFontWidth == decimal.MinValue)
            {
                var font = Styles.Fonts[0];
                System.Drawing.Font f = new System.Drawing.Font(font.Name, font.Size);
                _standardFontWidth=(decimal)(System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText("00", f).Width - System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText("0", f).Width);
            }
            if (_standardFontWidth == 0) _standardFontWidth = 7;
            return _standardFontWidth;
        }
    }
```

Of course this means building EPPlus from source, and you may have a different value for 7, but its a useful workaround for me!

Comment: Unlike a web or worker role, (where you can remote desktop) there is no GDI or Desktop in an Azure website, so there is no way to measure a thing with pixels if there is no desktop. (Kudos for Scott Hanselman for pointing this out on Twitter)

Comment: Good stuff, can see the issue is registered on Codeplex (http://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/14742). I've added a link to this question and to the issue (tracking).